# callback function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, design-patterns, callback, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to `return` an `object` inside a `callback function`

In the following situation, the `console.log()` show the result as expected

```
var dVizModule = (function(){
    let dataset;

    function loadData(fileName) {
        dataset = d3.csv(fileName, (data) => {
            dataset = data;
            console.log(dataset);
        });
    };

    return {
        loadData: loadData
    }

})();

dVizModule.loadData("data/time_scale_data.csv")
```

but when I try to use `return` in `callback function` the story is different and it returns `undefined`

```
var dVizModule = (function(){
    let dataset;

    function loadData(fileName) {
        dataset = d3.csv(fileName, (data) => {
            dataset = data;
            return dataset;
        });
        // return dataset; or even here!
    };

    return {
        loadData: loadData
    }

})();

console.log(dVizModule.loadData("data/time_scale_data.csv"))
```

Comment: `d3.csv` is an async function, and the `return dataset` statement is actually returning from the CB for `d3.csv()` function, and  `loadData()` is not returning anything.

Comment: You can make `loadData` return a promise like this : 

```
var dVizModule = (function(){
  let dataset;

  function loadData(fileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dataset = fs.readFile(fileName, (err,data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        dataset = data;
        resolve(dataset);
  
      });
    })
  };

  return {
      loadData: loadData
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a callback based workflow, the code above won't work. d3.csv is an asynchronous function, you can only get the result through a callback passed to it and hence even loadData needs to follow the same pattern.You just need to write something like this.

```js
var dVizModule = (function(){
    function loadData(fileName,callback) {
        d3.csv(fileName, (data) => {
            callback(data);
        });
    };
    return {
        loadData: loadData
    }

})();

dVizModule.loadData("data/time_scale_data.csv",(data)=>{
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: thats what exactly Im trying to avoid, passing a function to the API, is there any other solution ?

because d3 is this way in the architecure, Im trying to build a API like version of it